# Error message during CSS style sheet form installation on my Angular first project

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUEuc.jpg)on my way to build  my first Angular project I received this Error message: "**The Schematic workflow failed. See above.**" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ictWc.jpg)

Uninstalled Node and install the latest version, then I made update of Angular cli with: npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli ; npm cache verify ; "npm install -g @angular/cli" and npm update: "npm install -g npm" and to the end after the questions - when I choosed again CSS stylesheet format - I received the same red color error text: "The Schematic workflow failed. See above." ??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ictWc.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imboH.jpg)

Comment: That means that the Angular Schematics were not able to install the dependencies of the generated project. Can you please post the full error log? You've cut away the relevant parts...

Answer (score 0):

Clean your npm cache. Follow the steps as below:

```
npm cache verify
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install –g @angular/cli@latest
ng new <project-name>
```

Comment: I fixed the problem. First optimized my computer and installed windows latest updates.   After that uninstalled Node 16.08.0, and installed Node 14.17.6. Then cleaned the cache and uninstalled and installed again npm cli with those commands: 1. npm cache clean --force, 2 npm uninstall –g @an#4777gular/CLI, 3. npm install –g @an#4777gular/cli@latest. Then Deleted all files in the main folder "Angular project". Then built again ng new my-first-app - and this time after the CSS style sheet confirming, the installation completed successfully.